# How do I clamp horizontal axis rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts for this and how it is supposed to work is, if I enter a trigger, my `isClimbingWall` bool turns true which performs specific movements inside of my WallClimbing script. I also use that bool in my second script CameraLook in order to clamp my x-axis rotation.

```
// WallClimbing script
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        isClimbingWall = true;
    }
}
```

To get the clamp to work, I just add a quick if statement in the middle of my code so that if I am climbing, clamp x-axis rotation but it does not seem to work. I replaced `eulerAngles` with `AngleAxis` but I still get gimbal lock.

```
// CameraLook script
Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis(xAxis), Input.GetAxis(yAxis));

rotation.x += mouseDelta.x * sensitivity;

//Keep rotation in the range 0-360.
if (rotation.x < 0) rotation.x += 360f;
if (rotation.x > 360f) rotation.x -= 360f;

rotation.y += mouseDelta.y * sensitivity;
rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -yRotationLimit, yRotationLimit); // vertical clamp

if (wallClimbing.isClimbingWall)
{
    //horizontal clamp
    rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, -xRotationLimit, xRotationLimit); // xRotLimit 35f
}

var xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up);
var yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.y, Vector3.left);

transform.localRotation = yQuaternion; 
player.transform.rotation = xQuaternion;
```

However what happens is, no matter which angle the wall is positioned, when I enter the trigger my player/camera rotation will "snap" forward.

Comment: Usually you clamp at -180 degrees and +180 degrees.  Zero degrees is the positive x-axis.  Plus 90 degrees is the positive y-axis and negative 90 degrees is the negative y axis.  +/-180 degrees is the negative x-axis

Comment: I actually tried to remap the angle from [0, 360) to [-180, 180) to get this done and in my old attempt I had something like: `playerEulerAngles.y = (playerEulerAngles.y > 180) ? playerEulerAngles.y - 360 : playerEulerAngles.y;` which I then used in `Mathf.Clamp` but I couldn't produce any results

Comment: Try is it is greater than 180 make value 180 and if less than -180 make value -180.  If it is a wall you want to clamp at +/- 90.

Comment: `angle = (angle + 180) % 360;   if (angle < 0) { angle += 360; }    angle -= 180;`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes and then from there all I would have to do is add that updated angle line to my Mathf.Clamp() on top of my x-axis rotation limit like in my post inside that bool if statement?

Comment: Yes, if you want to limit the angle between -30 and + 30, for instance. I would create a function `NormalizeAngle` with my answer from above and then `Mathf.Clamp(NormalizeAngle(rotation.x), -yRotationLimit, yRotationLimit)`.

Comment: The Clamp alone will yield 35 for 270 but should yield -35, since 270 is the same as -90.

Comment: That information is a bit clearer now so I appreciate it, however despite all this, the issue still persists occasionally, depending on the y-rotation of the wall. So a wall with (0,0,0) rotation works fine, but on a wall like lets say (0,90f,0) will cause my camera to snap to 35 degrees forward upon entering the trigger

Comment: I've been having the same issue with my project, unfortunately I haven't been able to fix it yet

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser (for more than one question).

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the rotation to +/-35 degrees will yield +35 for 270 degrees by applying only `Clamp`, but should yield -35, since 270 is the same as -90.

Therefore, create a function which normalizes the angle between -180 and +180 degrees:

```cs
public static float NormalizeAngle(float angle)
{
    angle = (angle + 180) % 360;
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }
    return angle - 180;
}
```

Then you can write:

```cs
rotation.x =
    Mathf.Clamp(NormalizeAngle(rotation.x), -xRotationLimit, xRotationLimit);
```

Comment: I would rotate the camera towards (0,0,0) by the rotation angle of the wall, then do the normalization and clamping and finally rotate it back by the same angle.

Comment: I tried a solution to rotate my player so they are facing the object so that the angle would "reset", allowing for clamping no matter the rotation of the object, but it has not worked so far: https://pastebin.com/a6Ke9MJi I get the `transform.forward` and then use `Vector3.Angle` where I then use the angle in conjunction with your code to "reset" the angle right on player/wall contact so that the clamping issue goes away, but now when I turn right with my mouse to the x-axis rotation limit, the camera keeps bouncing back to the left almost infinitely.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I also have the same problem as the author. With the code above and the code you provided, how would you rotate towards (0,0,0) by the rotation angle of the wall followed by the rest?